# Clearing stdin after 'Press ENTER to continue'?

Tags: c, io, console-application, stdin, flush

I am attempting to let the user confirm his action by pressing the ENTER key - if any other key is pressed, the said 'action' does not occur.

However, instead of just a simple `if((ch=getchar())=='\n') {...}` , I actually want to clear `stdin` in case the user enters something like `hello\n` instead of letting that being read the next time I take input in my program.

The function I use to clear `stdin` is :

```c
void eat()
{
    int eat; while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}
```

However, this strategy leaves me with the user having to press ENTER *twice* , since it ' *eats* ' the newline that is supposed to make it send the input to my program (in a terminal).

What can be the simplest, most elegant solution ?

**NOTE :** I *cannot* use non-portable solutions like setting the console to send each character immediately by using the POSIX `terminos.h` .

Comment: In other words: you want to read a line. If it's empty, that's a confirmation, if not, not. So... `fgets`?

Comment: @dratenik that sounds *brilliant* - care to post an answer ?

Comment: Well, alright then.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to read a line and then check whether it's empty or not? Looks like a job for `fgets(..., stdin)`

```
char mystring [100];
fgets (mystring , 100 , stdin);
if (*mystring == '\n') {//confirmed}
```

Comment: wait... I can't really call `eat()` anymore without the *same* issues of it eating up the *last* `'\n'` which would mark the EOL , causing the user to have to press ENTER twice ...